# Choropleth Map with plotly.express doesn't show map, just legend

Tags: plotly, jupyter, choropleth, plotly-express

I copied the "Indexing by GeoJSON Properties" example as seen on the [Choropleth Maps in Python page](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/). The code was executed with no error but there was no map showing, only the legend. In addition, the 'box', 'pan', 'zoom' options show but don't work. I have the latest plotly version, installed via pip. any ideas? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Sometimes after lots of Plotly runs, the Plotly graphics stop showing the plots. Have you tried restarting your kernal, clearing the output, and the re-running that cell?

Comment: Thanks Jacob  I did try that with but with no success.

Comment: I just answered this question inside Data Science stack: [Choropleth Map with plotly.express doesn't show map, just legend](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/85147/choropleth-map-with-plotly-express-doesnt-show-map-just-legend/85648#85648)